# Get the current logged in users id for facebook application

Tags: facebook, api

Hey everyone
I'm developing a facebook app using the php facebook api
I am able to authenticate a user and get their friend list. But there seems to be something strange with the id's of the users friends list and the currently logged in users id, they are completely different!

The friends id's are 9 characters long and the currently logged in users is 16 characters long. What is up with this? Why is their two different ids?

Comment: different ids?! can you show us the code you are using to get these lists and the lists themselves?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I realised it's just an ol facebook account vs new facebook account thing. Older accounts only have 9 characters for the id, new ones have 16. Guess they underestimated the size of the site when it was created :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this for anyone else confused by the same thing. Older accounts only have 9 characters for the id, new ones have 16. Guess they underestimated the size of the site when it was created